# Is there a way to add multiple properties in the Unity 3d animation window at once?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

In Unity you can animate an object (such as a character) with the animation window:

[image: Animation Window]

And you can select properties of the object that you want to animate:

[image: Property Dropdown]

My problem is that it seems you can only add a **single** property at a time and then the whole list closes:

[image: Single Property]

This causes a big problem when you want to animate every part of a full human (or any type of complex) 3d model:

[image: All parts of model]

**My Question:** Is there some way I can add more than one property at the same time? Or atleast not have the window of properties close, that way I can just keep choosing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animation window will close after adding the property but their is a way to do this . Open animation window and inspector in separate tabs so that both can be seen at same time and **animation must be in recording mode** . After that **select your game object in hirarchy and you can directly change its properties from inspector** for each selected frame for example you can set position rotation and scale directly from inspector and this will make your animation in a fly :) Reference to unity documentation http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-MultipleParts.html

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple answer for a problem that was costing me so much time!

Comment: Unfortunately this is pretty useless for non-numeric properties. It's still going to be tedious for anything that requires a reference. For example, materials. You still need to pull up the library window and assign the reference manually. Unity's animation system is disgustingly tedious.

Answer (score 4):

Worth mentioning as well that if you right click on the transform instead of hitting the plus sign you can just add an entire group of transforms and the menu does not close. Should speed things up

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I've tested this method on Unity 2020.3.29f1, but it may work in earlier versions too.

1. In your hierarchy tab, select which bones you want to add properties for<sup>*</sup>. If you want to include all bones, select the parent bone and right click -> Select Children.
2. In your inspector tab, go to the Transform component and right click on Position, then select Add Key
3. Repeat step 2 for Rotation and Scale, if desired.

---

*: If you want to select multiple bones but not every bone, you can expand your list of bones and the use shift-click and ctrl-click (cmd-click) to select various bones.

Comment: THIS is the answer I came here for - THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!